# Can I change error popups for HTML5 form validation checks

Tags: html, forms, validation

I recently developed a form with HTML5 validation, and found that quite useful and easy then previous validation techniques, but now i am facing a requirement from the supervisor, i dont even know is possible or not due to my lack of practical knowledge of HTML5,

I just want to change the popup text which appears around the form element when something wrong is entered like, if we enter simple text in an email type form element and submit the form, then there will be a popup around this element saying "This must be an Email!"; and not allow to submit the form until right data is entered.

Is there any way of changing the text???

Comment: Can't really answer this without seeing what code you've developed so far . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, you can do changes by using jQuery and come css also as you like. You can even use plugins if you like.

```
<form class="example">
<div>
    <label for="your-name">Name: *</label>
    <input type="text" required="required" id="your-name" name="yourName" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

[check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/qTV3g/)

Comment: Well this is not something which i had in mind, but it was useful and fulfills my requirement, the only problem i have with this method is the reason i am replying after a long time; hope you understand  :p

Comment: thanks, if you have any kind of queries regarding it you can ask.i hope i can light them up.